# What math skills do I need to transpose this op-amp formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is not specific to op amps rather transposition... maybe?? I am not amazing at maths but I am beginning a journey to have at least some passable skills. First step was to read the mathjax tutorial to make this post..

done.

I have the following steps in a formaula

**Step 1**

$A_F = \frac{v_o}{v_i} $

**Step 2**

$ v_i = v_+ = v_- = \frac{R_1}{R_1+ R_2}  v_o$

**Step 3**

$A_F = \frac{v_o}{v_i} = 1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}$

In  going from step 1 to 3, I  feel that these steps have to be taken, please correct me as I become wrong.

$A_F = \frac{V_o}{\frac{R_1V_o}{R_1+R_2}}  $

dividing by a fraction the same as multiplying the very top line by the very bottom line

$A_F = \frac{V_0 R_1 +R_2}{R_1 V_o}$

$v_o$ on top and bottom line cancel to give 1.. where do I go from here to get to step 3 or where is my error?

$A_F = 1\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1}$

Comment: Note $\frac{a+b}{a} = \frac aa + \frac ba = 1 + \frac ba$.

Comment: Note also you should have parentheses around $R_1+R_2$ in your next-to-last equation.

Comment: Please do not use tags whose meaning you don't understand!